# How to pass POST Form Data from HTML to Java Rest Api

Tags: java, http, post, request

I am working on a Payment Integration System in Java Rest Api. 
The Gateway is Zaakpay. When a user clicks Proceed to payment my site is redirected to Zaakpay payment gateway. After a successful payment from Zaakpay it redirects the user to my `returnURL.html`. The Transaction Results are sent to `returnURL.htm`l as a POST Form Data in a HTTP Request.

How do I capture that POST Form Data in request and how do I forward it to Java Rest Api.

Comment: have you made nay REST service yet ?

Comment: Can we get some clarification? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think when payment Gateway (PG) redirects to my returnUrl I must capture the Post Request params using jquery/ajax and then forward it to my rest api.  Is it possible to capture Post Request params in jquery/ajax.  Another way i think could be to use redirection. please help out ....

Answer (score 1):

> **Why payment gateway is returning the result to `returnURL.html` ?**

I think you must have specified somewhere to indicate payment gateway to return result to this URL , So instead you can provide your Controller URL path .

After that in order to intercept the post request you need a method in your controller , So here is an example of `Jersey` based implementation of `JAX-RS`

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
public Response addUser(
    @FormParam("name") String name,
    @FormParam("age") int age) {

<================Do Whatever you need to do here ====================>

        return Response.status(200)
        .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age)
            .build();
 }
```

Comment: Neeraj thanks for your response. returnUrl.html will be the display page that calls my Rest Api Controller.  Since Zaakpay sends returnUrl.html a post request  I need a way to pass those post request parameters to my Rest Api. ( Like may be through Javascript or Jquert/ Ajax)